# Get ID of a NextGen album that is linked to a subpage

Tags: plugins, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I am trying to find the album ID of the album that is linked to a subpage of the parrent page that I am on.

Say I am on the page "Youth" and want to get the ID of the album that is linked to the subpage "galleries" (Youth -> Galleries).
How would I do this in PHP?

What I ultimately is after is to get the galleries from that album. I can get to those via $nggdb->find_album($ID), and then looping through $nggdb->find_gallery($galleryID); But I still need to get the ID of the album in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help from [Benjamin at the Wordpress support forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-id-of-the-album-that-is-linked-to-a-subpage?replies=3)

The solution I ended up with is the following:

```
global $nggdb;
$galleries = array();
$children = get_children("post_parent=$post->ID");
foreach($children as $kid) {
    print_r($kid);
    $page_id = $kid->ID;
    $album_mapper = C_Album_Mapper::get_instance();
    $albums = $album_mapper->find_all(array('pageid = %s', $page_id), TRUE);
    foreach ($albums as $albumMap) {
        $albumID = $albumMap->ID();
```

After finding the albumID, I begin finding the galleries in this album

```
        $album = $nggdb->find_album($albumID);
        if($album) {
            foreach( $album->gallery_ids as $galleryid ){
                $gallery    = $nggdb->find_gallery($galleryid);
                $image      = $nggdb->find_image( $gallery->previewpic );
                $galleries[$galleryid]['title'] = $gallery->title;
                $galleries[$galleryid]['url']   = home_url() . $post->post_name . '/' . $kid->post_name . '/?album=all&gallery=' . $galleryid;
                $galleries[$galleryid]['image'] = ($image->thumbURL) ? '<img src="' . $image->thumbURL . '" />' : '';
            }
            $i = 1;
            foreach($galleries as $category){
                echo '<div class="galleryContainer">'
                        . '<a href="' . $category['url'] . '" class="galleryImage">'
                            . $category['image']
                            . '<div class="galleryTitle">'
                                . $category['title']
                            . '</div>'
                        . '</a>'
                    . '</div>';
                if ($i++ == 3) break;
            }
        } else {
            echo 'No galleries at this time, sorry :/';
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help others, it works for me :)